# Custom property value not available in constructor normal property values show

Tags: winforms, user-controls

Simple setup

Have a user control let's call it UserControl1 with bunch of labels, textbox etc. I place this UserControl1 on a Form and change a custom property "AppName" text to "My New App Name"

The issue is that "My New App Name" is not available in the constructor but load in "Load" event. However, if I set the text property of a label in UserControl1 to "My Text" it's available in Constructor and Load.

All my custom properties are shown in the design view with no problem and I am setting the custom prperty "AppName" in design view.

Winform
Visual Studio 2015
.net 4.5

Thnx in advance to all who help
Cheers,

Hello Jimi, Here are the screen shots to understand it a bit better

[Custom properties in a user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci6vp.png)

[User control placed on a form and I've set this property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4XnH.png)

[Form loads and a breakpoint in the user control. No value in constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmfc8.png)

[When it reaches load, it's there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LMIo.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you set a property value in the designer, it's available in the Form's constructor after the `InitializeComponent` method has completed the initialization proc.

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't. It works but for built in properties only. As a hack I've transferred code to Load which I don't like but for now till someone solves it

Comment: Can you show the code related to this Property?

Comment: Hey Jimi, Thnx for helping out, I've attached pics. Can make a small project to show the issue as well

Comment: But, you meant in the **User Control**'s Constructor! How can a property of a Control, set in a Form's Designer, be available in the Control's Constructor? The Form first builds a new Control instance (here the Control's Constructor will be called), then it sets its properties, then loads it.

Comment: Why does it show changes to it's own properties such label, textbox etc then?

Comment: What's **it**? The User Control? In the UC Constructor, all properties are initialized to the values defined at design time. Follow the loading procedure of the Form (which contains the UC in question) as described in the previous comment. If you set a property of the UC in the Form, this property will be set only **after** the UC has been initialized. `[Form Initialize] => [child Controls Initialize] => [Set child Controls' properties]`. If a UC property is set in the Form designer, the property will be set in step 3, whicle the UC initialization occurs in step 2.